# python lists values

Tags: python

i want to create a list or a dictionary not sure which niether have worked so far
i need to convert text (user input) into numeric value and add them together
there are 4 possible answers 
this is how i want it to work

each box contains fruit and are sold for differant prices

```
apple=25,oranges=35,pears=10,bananas=50,pineapple=40
totalprice=0
count=5
list = [box1,box2,box3,box4,box5,]
while count >0:
fruit=raw_input("what fruit is in ")(0)
count -=1
if fruit ==apples:
return "price 25"
totalprice=+25
```

i want this to run five times gathering the total price along the way

is there a away that whatever fruit they put in the corresponding value will be added to total price.
sorry if not explained very well new to programming

Comment: What do you want with this code having tons of issues? Should we fix your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it would make sense to use a `dict` to store fruit name - > price.

```
fruits = {
    'apples': 25,
    'oranges': 35,
    'pears': 10,
    'bananas': 50,
    'pineapples': 40
}
```

Then we create an empty list, and loop over the numbers from 1 to 5 (note that 6 isn't included in the range)...

```
inputs = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    inputs.append(raw_input('Enter fruit for box {}: '.format(i)))
```

We then use `sum` that takes the inputs, and tries to look up the value in `fruits`...

```
print sum(fruits[name] for name in inputs)
```

Sample run:

```
Enter fruit for box 1: bananas
Enter fruit for box 2: bananas
Enter fruit for box 3: bananas
Enter fruit for box 4: pears
Enter fruit for box 5: apples
185
```

Other things you could do are validate a fruit exists before appending it to `inputs` - but this should be enough for you to work with for the moment.

Comment: Like your solution, it's really pythonic but it seems to be a little bit too complex for Miguel who is a beginner

Comment: Thanks goranek i understand your code i tried it out with whatt i want to do.

Comment: thanks jon , Ill need a fresh head to understand your code , will try manana. adios y gracias

Answer (score 5):

```
fruits = {"apple":25,"oranges":35,"pears":10,"bananas":50,"pineapple":40}
total_price = 0

for _ in range(0,5):
    fruit = raw_input("Fruit: ")
    if fruit in fruits:
        totalprice += fruits[fruit]

print total_price
```

Is this what you want? To ask 5 times for a fruit, and then print sum of price of all fruits written?

Comment: thanks goranak i will try this and let you know if it works. i hope my questions become a little less stupid in time